# Why won't my Google Plus javascript validate?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google +1 Button not W3C compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217434/google-1-button-not-w3c-compliant)

My javascript for google plus fails w3c validation. Can you tell me why?

Here is the error message:

```
Line 53, Column 407: Element name g:plusone cannot be represented as XML 1.0.

…hgoogle.png" alt="Logo"></a><g:plusone></g:plusone><a href="https://www.facebo…

✉
Error Line 53, Column 407: Element g:plusone not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

…hgoogle.png" alt="Logo"></a><g:plusone></g:plusone><a href="https://www.facebo…
```

Comment: What JavaScript? Isn't this an html validation failure?

Comment: It won't validate because Google provided you with invalid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with mine, If you are using HTML5 it will not validate, unless you use the code specific for HTML5, unfortunately I cannot give you my code snippet at this moment in time however here

https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

It's just under the subtitle +1 Tag